# How to develop cloud independent application

Tags: cloud

How to write a application that works on all the cloud platform and it can be deploy on any cloud.

Note :- I am using cloud storage service like SQS and DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use open stack to develop cloud independent application.

here you can get more detail about [Open Stack.](http://docs.openstack.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform you use. For java for example there are libraries ([dasein](http://dasein-cloud.sourceforge.net/), [jclouds](http://jclouds.incubator.apache.org/)) which provides unified interface for many cloud [providers](http://jclouds.incubator.apache.org/documentation/userguide/).

Comment: I am developing application on .Net Platform. Is there any libraries are available for .Net ???